# setOnItemClickListener() for ListView is not working

Tags: java, android, listview, selection

[This is chat which is to be translate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qru6U.jpg)

[This is the activity using listview to show languages and i have to select one language and save it to translate chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLZqG.jpg)

I have an activity in which I'm using list view to show all languages using bing api, but on language selection activity crashed,I basically have to save the selected language in a variable for another use but its not working,
 I have wrote the following code and don't know why this is not working while i tried all sort of methods but can't exactly understand the issue here

```
public void initViews() {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GetAllValues());
    final ListView lang = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.select_lang);
    lang.setAdapter(adapter);
    loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoading);
    loading.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

    lang.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Selected_Language = languages[parent.getSelectedItemPosition()];
         // Selected_Language = lang.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Selected_Language = languages[parent.getSelectedItemPosition()].toString();
            new MessageChatAdapter(mcontext);
            writeToFile(Selected_Language);
            Toast.makeText(mcontext,"Language Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        }
    });
}
```

This is complete java file, The code was working fine with spinner but when i used `listView` it's not working:

```
 package com.fyp.voicechat.ui;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.fyp.voicechat.R;
 import com.fyp.voicechat.adapter.MessageChatAdapter;
 import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.Locale;

public class Setting_Activity extends Activity {
Language[] languages = Language.values();
public static String language;
ProgressBar loading;
public String Selected_Language;
public static Context mcontext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting_);
    mcontext = this;

    initViews();
    Locale loc = new Locale("en");
    Log.i("-------------", Arrays.toString(loc.getAvailableLocales()));
}


public void initViews() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GetAllValues());
    final ListView lang = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.select_lang);
    lang.setAdapter(adapter);
    loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoading);
    loading.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

    lang.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Selected_Language = languages[parent.getSelectedItemPosition()];
           // Selected_Language = lang.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Selected_Language = languages[parent.getSelectedItemPosition()].toString();
            new MessageChatAdapter(mcontext);
            writeToFile(Selected_Language);
            Toast.makeText(mcontext,"Language Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        }
    });
  /*  spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, GetAllValues());
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    send = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivSend);
    //spin.setVisibility(Spinner.INVISIBLE);
    loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbLoading);
    loading.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Selected_Language = languages[spin.getSelectedItemPosition()].toString();
            new MessageChatAdapter(mcontext);
           writeToFile(Selected_Language);
            Toast.makeText(mcontext,"Language Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });*/
}
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
public String[] GetAllValues(){
    String lan[] = new String[languages.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < languages.length; i++){
        lan[i] = languages[i].name();
    }
    return lan;
}
```

}

Comment: Show the code for the whole `Activity` please and the logcat output also.

Comment: why do you use languages[parent.getSelectedItemPosition()].toString(); instead of languages[position].toString() ?

Comment: Because i need language type, i did use that as well but translation doesn't work

Comment: Language[] languages = Language.values();

Comment: new MessageChatAdapter(mcontext); this is useless. You create an instance, but you get no reference.

Comment: but i think this is not the main issue here 
when i switched from spinner to listview then it started to have issues 
i think this line have some problem 
 Selected_Language = languages[parent.getSelectedItemPosition()].toString();

Comment: Because when i wrote this one the language saved successfully but i have problem in translation then 
Selected_Language = parent.getSelectedItemPosition().toString();

Comment: You want `languages[posittion]`. I don't know why you are trying to use `parent.getSelectedItemPosition`

Comment: Then what should i use??

Comment: Thankyou @cricket-007
it's just worked